# What is your opinion on using ChatGPT for building vocabulary and improving sentence structures?

Tags: sentence-construction

My English language skills including vocabulary and sentence structure are very weak. I am going to take GRE in couple of weeks and I tried using ChatGPT for improving my English language skills. Is there a potential downside to using this approach? What are your opinions about it? Thanks :-)

Comment: I feel like this may be closed as "too opinion-based", although it is an interesting question.

Comment: @stangdon - how about 'insufficient research' as an alternative reason?

Comment: It's a "meta" question, on a par with requests for resources. For what it's worth, I normally expect to easily recognize most non-native Anglophones from just a small amount of text typed in here on ELL, but in all the countless thousands of words I've read while interacting with ChatGPT, I don't recall ever seeing anything to suggest it was less than flawlessly fluent in English.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access or interactions with a real native speaker, then an AI one may be a good alternative.  Some caveats:

AI's are tuned to write, not talk.  They tend to produce bland essay-style writing.  It is free of grammar errors (certainly it is more accurate than most native speakers) but it tends to be a bit plain.

Secondly, AIs don't actually know about grammar.  They may pretend to know, but they don't actually have access to their own programming.  So if you ask them a question about grammar they might make something up.  They might telly you, in perfect English, that the verb comes at the start of the clause.  They might tell you that "cat is usually spelled K E T" and so on. They are not capable of introspection. You can't ask an AI to explain their own mind, they just don't know about it (but if you ask them, they will probably make something up).  An AI won't be able to correct your grammar, because it don't know about grammar.

Finally, you might get bored talking to an AI.  I don't get bored talking to my friends, because they have interesting opinions, and take a real interest in what I'm saying.  AIs generate text automatically, and they can get a bit boring - which means you'll quit.

But if you enjoy it, and want to have a native speaker that will never tire of talking to you, and remember that it only knows English, and doesn't know *about* English, then a Generative AI may be a good tool to practice English with.